# Running elm reactor through a reverse proxy: How can I add an url prefix to links to _elm?

Tags: elm, elm-reactor

The html file served by elm reactor contains links to _elm/styles.css and
_elm/elm.js

I am now trying to run elm reactor via a reverse proxy
which routes http://myhost/myprefix to http://localhost:8000.

However this would require that the links refer to myprefix/_elm/*

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elm Reactor is quite limited and only meant to get you started. Maybe something like [Elm Live](https://www.elm-live.com/) will give you better results. It has at least some config options regarding proxies you might want to take a look at.

Comment: Actually elm-live -x myprefix  -y http://myhost src/MyElm.elm worked for me. Thank you